# Lotus Notes embedded view from other database using formula?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

When creating an embedded view, a popup will appear asking from which database and which view to embed. There's also an option to use @formula to specify the view. Selecting that will present 2 more option 'Display' (radio button): 'View' and 'Formula'. How do I write formula to select view 'Employee' from 'Database B'? Let's say I'm currently in 'Database A'. In the form I already passed value for 'Database B' server and file name/path in the fields 'svr' and 'db'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.  You can only specify the view name which corresponds to views within the current database.

See more information here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/0/8b60e2b8c9c3223c852572e2004cbd79?OpenDocument

Just a thought:  I'm not sure if this is possible, but perhaps you could add the two embedded views into your form and then hide/show them?  They wouldn't be based on a formula, but deciding whether they show/hide could be based on a formula.

Comment: Ken is right, however instead of using hide-whens, I would suggest using two subforms, each one with one of the embedded views, and a computed subform formula.  That seems slightly cleaner to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it: http://dmcnally.blogspot.com/2011/01/configurable-embedded-views-single.html

It is an extensive writeup so I won't describe it here.

I've been using this solution for ages, works pretty well.